# Run Java application from windows command line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, command-line

So I'm totally new to java development and am working on a school project.. This is also my first post on SO.. I have two related issues. First I'm getting the "Error: Could not find or load main class Main" when I attempt to run my code from the command line. I believe this is related to the classpath but I don't understand why it isn't running main? Perhaps related to the package? I would expect it to possibly not find the the commons lib due to the path by why main?

[command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZeCW.png)

Here are some snap shots of the code:

[main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC36v.png)

[cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6zTN.png)

The second issue is when I pass arguments into Intellij (config below..) it does not catch them at hasOption("foo")..

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7TrG.png)

[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DHZx.png)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Post all the relevant code and commands in the question, as text. Not as links to images. Images are not searchabl. They can't be edited, copied and pasted and modified.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should read and understand how classpath is used. Your classpath variable is set to the apache commons lib. This means it's the *only* place it would search for your main class. In fact, you want it to first search in your current directory tree. So you need to set CLASSPATH to `.;[other libs...]` (where `.` denotes the current directory.) Then you need to `CD [...]\sim-comm-shell` and type `java com.demand.energy.Main` since the `java` command needs a fully-qualified class name.

The second part: options have a hyphen in front of them. Your command line should be `-h`.

Comment: For the first I added ".;" to the classpath and did this:
C:\Class Material\Demand\sim-comm-shell\out\production\sim-comm-shell>java com.demandenergy.simcommand.Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
        at com.demandenergy.simcommand.Main.main(Main.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException..etc.. 

It now runs the code (thank you!) but doesn't see the apache lib. Step in the right direction!

Comment: What exactly did you set CLASSPATH to? You need to add *both* the current directory *and* the apache lib. `CLASSPATH=.;c:\path\to\lib.jar`.